# Read binary file as String, edit and then back to Binary file in Android Studio (java)

Tags: java, android

I am new to java and I code a mobile app on Android Studio 3.1x.

I need to read a binary file as String. (Eg: abc.dll)

Need to edit some portion of that string and write back to another binary file.
Eg: efg.dll

I could do it well, but when I read as String, the String looks different and wrong length.

I know I can patch that byte[] and re write the byte[] as efg.dll.
But I need to convert as String and back to byte[] and write efg.dll for some reason.

My pseudo code is below:

```
String FileBuffer ="";
int FileLength = 0;

//I store abc.dll inside raw folder
InputStream ipsSysTemplate =  getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.abc);
FileLength = ipsSysTemplate.available();
byte[] buf = new byte[FileLength];
ipsSysTemplate.read(buf);
ipsSysTemplate.close();
FileBuffer = new String(buf); 
//I even tried many Charset like "UTF-8", "windows-1252" etc...
//FileBuffer = new String(buf,"UTF-8");  

//I need both length must be same, but I get different
System.out.println(FileLength + "  " + FileBuffer.length());

//Finally I write a new binary file efg.dll from below code
File file = new File(/storage/emulated/0/Download/efg.dll);
file.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(FileBuffer.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

When I do this similar code in Eclipse on Window 7, I get expected result.
But in that case I place my template abc.dll on HDD.

I don't know where is the issue and what I need to know more...
On the concept of java or Android mobile.

Could some expert understand my problem and give me a simple solution please ?

This is how both files look after my code.
[please have a look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6PuM.jpg)

Thanks in advance...

gaamaa

Comment: Binary files are not text, so you should not try to read them as one.

Comment: I do same in Visual Basic and get proper result.
Now I need VB app on android mobile for handy.
That's why I need this.
There must be a way to read binary garbage as same garbage on string right ?

Comment: I don't think anyone should be using VB as an example of what to do.

Comment: If you're insistent on using Strings, I suggest using a google library. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/ByteString

Comment: String s1 = new String(new byte[] {buf[i]}, "windows-1252");

Finally works like charm and I have completed my project successfully.
Thanks for your pep...

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Strings to process binary data. Your binary viewer is likely rendering the text in raw ascii, which is a 1-to-1 relation of char to byte. Most modern charsets however do not follow that. In fact, unicode defines a variable number of bytes per character.

If you really wanted to, you could cast each `byte` in your array to `char`, and feed that into String. However I recommend finding a way to do it using just `byte[]` or even a `ByteBuffer`.

Comment: Thanks again Killjoy, let me try google lib and I am trying below code to covert each byte as char.

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i < buf.length; i++){
                String s1 = new String(new byte[] {buf[i]}, "windows-1252");
                System.out.println(s1);
                sb.append(s1);
            }
    FileBuffer = sb.toString();